# How to mimic receiving data from a server when data and server are local?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, redux, server

I don't know how to ask this question, but i have a react redux project that show some products with some functionality like filtering and sorting..etc

I have created a json file that represents the data and i need to mimic receiving this data from a server that i have already created using **express** as if i receive data from a remote server.

I have no knowledge about backend so i am confused how can i do that, i feel there is a lost piece so i can not make a connection between data and server and the project.

What is the key to achieve that ??

Comment: You can use myjson(http://myjson.com/) and upload your JSON data there. And you can use that data as an api.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to achieve that locally??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above either use myjson or you can use [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) package.

In your project folder, you just need to create a json file ex. local-api.json

ex :

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ],
  "comments": [
    { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
  ],
  "profile": { "name": "typicode" }
}
```

and you can run it like this :

```
json-server --watch local-api.json
```

**Note**: example is taken from there to make you understand. You can explore more about this package in their GitHub website

For more reference go there GitHub site : [here](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

Express server example

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({"hello":"world"})) //add your data

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

run this file using node index.js and make sure you install express(
`npm install express --save`)
And then you can fetch in your component like this :

```
componentDidMount(){
axios.get("http://localhost:5000").then(data => //your logic)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, but the purpose  of the project is educational and i need to write some code to make the connection, i need to achieve that without using any tools, how can i do that??

Comment: Then only you can do it by creating a local server. And make api request to it. For  ex: your server is running on port 5000, You can make a request like http://localhost:5000 and from there you can return your JSON

Comment: can you add this part to the original answer with some details so i can understand more and accept your answer..thanks this is really helpful

Comment: I have updated my code. Let me know if you have any doubt